# PHP scripts not working after migrating to PHP7

Tags: php, mysql, apache, rhel6

After migrating to `PHP7.2` from `PHP5.5` , my PHP scripts are not getting executed however `phpinfo()` is loading fine . I have installed `php` from source code .

I have enabled display_errors setting and it showing the following messages

```
[03-Oct-2018 16:32:12 UTC] PHP Warning:  Creating default object from empty value in config.php on line 163

[03-Oct-2018 16:32:12 UTC] PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in get.php on line 25
```

[03-Oct-2018 16:32:12 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined property: stdClass::$Array in get.php on line 25

But these are warnings and notices .
Am I missing some configuration to make the code work ?

Comment: Did you update your Apache configuration? The Apache DLL for PHP changed names between PHP 5 and PHP 7.

Comment: Do you know that your scripts are 7.2 compatible? You might be using deprecated functionality.

Comment: What about the scripts are not working? Have you checked the server error logs?

Comment: Edited my questions with errors

Comment: Sounds like differences between versions. Track down the code where the errors are occuring and fix them.

Answer (score 1):

On the first error in config.php file, you probably should instantiate a new stdClass() like the example below:

```
$var = new stdClass()
```

and then assign a value to its properties.

On the second error, you must have assigned the var as an array and then trying to echo that var

Without seeing the code I think its all the help I could give you